# Problem with verifying an ECDSA Signature with openssl

Tags: openssl, digital-signature

I am using openssl to verify ECDSA Signatures of a smartcard.
However, I am running in trouble with two cards.
A challenge is sent to the card, signed and then sent back. the signature is verified using the public key.

I have posted a [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/174095/convert-ecdsa-signature-from-plain-to-der-format/174133#174133) here before, where I was asking how to convert the plain signature I get from the card to DER format. That one has been answered and I got it working. But the signature does not verify for all cards (`EVP_DigestVerifyFinal()` returns 0).
I did verify with a different system that the signatures coming from the card are indeed verifiable with the public key. However I can't look into the code of that system.

Below is the code for the verification, with the function to convert the signature at the bottom.

I'm not a crypto expert. Am I missing a setting here that needs to go into `EVP_DigestVerifyInit()` for example? Does it always need to be initialized with `EVP_sha1()`? 
Thank you for your answers!

```
bool doAA(std::vector<unsigned char> oRND, std::vector<unsigned char> oSIG, std::vector<unsigned char> oPKEY)
{
    EVP_PKEY* m_pPubkey;
    BIO* keyBio = BIO_new_mem_buf(&oPKEY[0], (int)oPKEY.size());
    m_pPubkey = d2i_PUBKEY_bio(keyBio, NULL);       
    BIO_free(keyBio);

    if (NULL == m_pPubkey)
    {
        std::cout << "Error Public key is NULL" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // check if ECDSA signature and then verify
    int nRes = 0;
    int type = EVP_PKEY_base_id(m_pPubkey);
    if (type == EVP_PKEY_EC)
    {
        EVP_MD_CTX* ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();

        nRes = EVP_DigestVerifyInit(ctx, NULL, EVP_sha1(), NULL, m_pPubkey);
        if (1 != nRes)
        {
            EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
            std::cout << "Error EVP_DigestVerifyInit" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        nRes = EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate(ctx, &oRND[0], oRND.size());
        if (1 != nRes)
        {
            EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
            std::cout << "Error EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        ConvertPlainToDERSignature(oSIG);

        nRes = EVP_DigestVerifyFinal(ctx, &oSIG[0], oSIG.size());
        EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
        if (nRes < 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Error EVP_DigestVerifyFinal failed" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        else if (nRes == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Error EVP_DigestVerifyFinal: Signature could not be verified" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Not a ECDSA Signature" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return nRes == 1;
}

void ConvertPlainToDERSignature(std::vector<unsigned char>& raSignature)
{
    ECDSA_SIG* ec_sig = ECDSA_SIG_new();
    int nLen = raSignature.size() / 2;
    if (NULL == BN_bin2bn(&raSignature[0], nLen, (ec_sig->r)))
    {
        std::cout << "OpensslError " << std::string(ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL)) << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "ECDSA Signature R: " << std::string(BN_bn2hex(ec_sig->r)) << std::endl;;

    if (NULL == BN_bin2bn(&raSignature[0] + nLen, nLen, (ec_sig->s)))
    {
        std::cout << "OpensslError " << std::string(ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL)) << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "ECDSA Signature S: " << std::string(BN_bn2hex(ec_sig->s)) << std::endl;;

    int sig_size = i2d_ECDSA_SIG(ec_sig, NULL);
    unsigned char *sig_bytes = new unsigned char[sig_size];
    unsigned char *p;
    memset(sig_bytes, 6, sig_size);

    p = sig_bytes;
    int new_sig_size = i2d_ECDSA_SIG(ec_sig, &p);

    raSignature.clear();

    raSignature.resize(new_sig_size);

    memcpy(&raSignature[0], sig_bytes, new_sig_size);
    delete[] sig_bytes;
}
```

Comment: *"Problem with verifying an ECDSA Signature with openssl"* - You never state what the problem is. What is the problem?